# How to extract colours from UIImage using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, colors, uiimage

I recently started to create an iOS version of my Android app and I've found myself struggling to find a method of extracting dominant colours from an image.

Over in Android there's a palette library provided by Google that allows you to do just that. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html)

I'm can't seem to find any libraries that will allow me to that in iOS however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems my friend use this library: https://github.com/pixelogik/ColorCube

Take a tour, it seems that they do what you are expected.

Comment: Can I use ObjC libraries with Swift?

Comment: Yes of course: 
official doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH2-XID_0
Tutorial: https://medium.com/swift-programming/merge-objective-c-static-library-into-swift-using-mosquitto-87ce0b6ec513